# How to make "message" and "channel" defineable under one ()

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I'm setting up a bot (VSC, Discord.JS) to do the following; if you send one message in a specific channel, you are instantly given a role that makes you unable to speak in the channel again. 
So basically a one time message channel that you can still read before or after. 
The one-time message and read before or after part is still covered. But programming the bot to automate the process isn't covered. The console says that channel.id cannot be defined, there is no definition and I don't know how to add it in.

Condensed Summary :
How do I combine the message and channel definition into one?

I've searched up on Google for solutions to combine message and channel definitions together but failed, I couldn't find any.

doopliss.on('message', function(message){

```
if(message.content == 'a')
if(channel.id == '539228268893569044')
{
    member.gulid.roles.find("name", "Quote Banned");
    member.addrole("name", "Quote Banned");
}})
```

I expect: The bot to know when you type "a" then you are given the Quote Banned role if "a" is said in the channel with the specified ID

What actually happened: When saying "a" in the channel with the specified ID, the console shows an error and asks for the definition of channel, and you aren't given the role at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you try and access `channel`. If you do `channel.id` your code searches for a variable named `channel`, which you presumably don't have set, and tries to call the `id` property of that variable. What (I think) you need is `message.channel.id`.

Adding to that is that you try to find the "Quote Banned" role from the guild based on a variable `member` which you don't have defined either. Furthermore you don't save the found role anywhere to later assign it to the user.

Take a look at this code and give that a try.

```js
doopliss.on('message', function(message) {
  if(message.content == 'a') {
    if(message.channel.id == '539228268893569044') {
      let bannedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Quote Banned");
      message.member.addRole(bannedRole);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It said this when I put it in

TypeError: message.member.addrole is not a function

Comment: According to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) that should work. Try logging the `bannedRole` and see what that says. Perhaps the role can't be found

Comment: I've just seen my mistake, it's not `addrole`, it needs to be `addRole` (capitalization is important). I'll update my answer

Comment: It just gave out this error code

(node:40514) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

Comment: @SomePerson I have updated my answer once again, it now has a function in the `.find` of the array